# OK to reposition a 90 degree sweep of Schedule 40 conduit after it's been glued?

Tags: electrical, conduit

[image]I've installed 2" Schedule 40 direct burial pipe from power pole to power pole so that AT&T, Comcast, & Wave aerial cables can be run underground instead.  I've completed the conduit connections and have run pull rope through each.  However, the 90 degree sweep for the middle conduit is not aligned with the power pole (see photo) by a couple of feet.  I'm not sure if I forced this conduit up against the pole and secured it if it would cause stress and possibly break the conduit or cause one of the glued connections to separate.  I'd prefer not to have to realign it by cutting the conduit and installing another connector if I can avoid it since I've already run the pull rope through the length of the conduit.

Comment: Is that deep enough?

Comment: The trench is 2 ft deep, which is what the specs state for communication conduit.

Comment: Enticing a glued connection to break would be the best possible option.  Though PVC cement is close to welding.

Answer (score 6):

I would really try to avoid placing intentional stress on the PVC pipe to get it into position.

Instead you should find the part of the pipe that is relatively straight where a cut and rotation of the pipe on its center axis will correct for the misalignment at the end. Then cut open the pipe and glue in a coupler to allow for the rotation.

The rope should be no problem. Tie on some more rope at the existing end and then when you cut the pipe do so in a manner that you do not cut off the rope. Once the pipe is open pull the extra rope down toward your cut area and open the knot so you can thread on the new coupling fitting. Then rejoin the knot and pull the rope back through to the end. Re-glue the joint with the rope inside the fitting.

Comment: I tossed a +1 in here for the knotted pull rope description. It seems rather clear, one might say obvious that it's an easy way to make a fix and not lose the pull rope, but I'd have not thought of it without seeing this post. Slicing the straight section and rotating it in a coupling makes more sense than a heat/twist option. Heating and twisting adds a possibility of collapsing the pipe, although with 2" diameter, a little squish might not matter.

Answer (score 2):

You could heat the conduit with a blow dryer and twist it into place. It will probably make a small twist in it but it will be buried so it will all look the same.

Another concern though is a rope or cord to pull wire in PVC. If it is a soft rope with many fibers it will usually be ok. But steel leader cable, cord, or small poly rope can cut right through a 90° if too much stress is placed on it. We use kite string to cut PVC when it's already in a trench and it works real good. Normally we use rigid 90°'s for PVC conduits that will be under high stress while pulling. Go slow and use lots of pulling lube or you will have a disaster on your hands.

Good luck!